# How do I using Roboflow's "CSV: Tensorflow Object Detection" format in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, keras, roboflow

How do I using Roboflow's "CSV: Tensorflow Object Detection" format in Tensorflow?

I have annotated and augmented several images in Roboflow for object detection. As I am using an iPython Notebook on Google Colab to form the machine learning model with Tensorflow, I chose to export the images in the "Tensorflow Object Detection" format under "CSV" and uploaded the data in a folder to my Google Drive.

However, I have no idea how to get the annotated data to a form that tensorflow.keras can use (to be specific, my model is a tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential object). The only solutions I could find around on the internet use the terminal, but I need something that works in an iPython Notebook on Google Colab. I want to be able to create my own model rather than use something like YOLOv5 PyTorch in this case.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is usually used as an intermediate format for the Tensorflow Object Detection tfrecord files. We have a tutorial on it here: https://blog.roboflow.com/train-a-tensorflow2-object-detection-model/

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll take a look at that!

Comment: The tutorial was helpful in understanding how to open the zip file. However, it seemed to depend on an exterior model called "EfficientDet" (assuming I understood it correctly) and pretrained weights. Could you kindly point me to a way I can use the information from the file in a model I make myself with tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential?

Comment: There's a ton of work you'd have to do to get object detection working with that. That's why they have the Tensorflow Object Detection library. They have the configs you can modify here but they're not as low level as you're probably looking for: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/configs/tf2

If you want to edit the actual model structure PyTorch may be easier. Eg here's the model config for YOLOv5s where you can edit the convolutional layers etc: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/models/yolov5s.yaml

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at PyTorch!